# 404 on source.yaml rosdistro file

Tags: ros, pre-release, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am following the [instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest) on the ROS Wiki for setting up a pre-release test for a catkin package.  In several places in the documentation including [Step 3](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest#Development_test_.28test_from_development.2BAC8-upstream_repository.29) , reference is made to a source.yaml file.  However, no such file appears to exist anywhere in the rosdistro package.  Consequently, I'm not sure how to even get started.

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188612/404-on-source.yaml-rosdistro-file/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file is not called `source.yaml` anymore but `distribution.yaml`. I have updated the wiki page accordingly: http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest?action=diff&rev1=22&rev2=23

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2014-08-01**:
Thanks Dirk!